# Не правильно работает моторчик на Ардуино

Tags: c++, arduino

При нажатии на кнопку мотор крутится.Когда отпускаю перестает крутится и реагировать на кнопку. То есть по идее кнопка должна крутить мотор при нажатии и остановится при отпускании. Но на следующий клик она не запускает моторчик.Скорее всего проблема в том что при нажатии идет сигнал на драйвер мотора а при отпускании сигнал остается а по идеи он должен исчезать.Проблем наверное в коде.Вот посмотрите может кто то поможет

```
#include <CustomStepper.h>            // Подключаем библиотеку управления шаговым двигателем. По умолчанию настроена на двигатель 28BYJ-48-5V
CustomStepper stepper(8, 9, 10, 11);  // Указываем пины, к которым подключен драйвер шагового двигателя
const int pin_button = 2;
int example = 1;                      // Переменная для демонстрации работы, отвечающая за смену режимов
bool x;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    stepper.setRPM(12);                 // Устанавливаем кол-во оборотов в минуту
    stepper.setSPR(4075.7728395);       // Устанавливаем кол-во шагов на полный оборот. Максимальное значение 4075.7728395
    pinMode(pin_button, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    x = digitalRead(pin_button);
    Serial.print(x);

    if(x == 1) {

        if(stepper.isDone() and example == 1)  // Когда предыдущая команда выполнена (см. ниже), метод stepper.isDone() возвращает true
        {
            stepper.setDirection(CW);         // Устанавливает направление вращения. Может принимать 3 значения: CW - по часовой, CCW - против часовой, STOP
            stepper.rotate(2);                // Устанавливает вращение на заданное кол-во оборотов
            example = 2;
        }
        if(stepper.isDone() and example == 2)
        {
            stepper.setDirection(STOP);
            stepper.rotateDegrees(0);        // Поворачивает вал на заданное кол-во градусов. Можно указывать десятичную точность (например 90.5), но не принимаются отрицательные значения
            example = 1;
        }


        stepper.run();                      // Этот метод обязателен в блоке loop. Он инициирует работу двигателя, когда это необходимо
    }
    example = 1;

}
```

Comment: @vp_arth он там лишний

Comment: @vp_arth забыл его удалить но он роли не играет

Comment: Также Вам нужно добавить `else` перед вторым if. Иначе будут выполняться обе инструкции.

Comment: А какай смысл проверять `example == 2` если на каждом цикле `example` устанавливается в 1?